# Using TFS's RestApi to find stories tied to a commit

Tags: git, tfs

My team is using Team Foundation Server 2017 to track UserStories and we store our repo's in TFS Git as well, in the same project. I want to use TFS's rest api to help our team document changes through each sprint.

Using a commitID, do I have a way to find all the Userstories that have a tie to that commit? I do see that Userstories have a link to a commit associated with them, but do I have the ability to look at all stories tied to the commitID?

Thanks,

Comment: It's able to use Rest API fetch the linked commit for a specific user story. Did you just want to do the opposite, fetch all linked user stories for a specific GIT commit?

Comment: Yes - I know you can go from User story to commit, but I'm not seeing an easy way to go from commit to userstory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want query GIT commits to get related works item IDs associated with particular commit.

You could use below Rest API **with optional parameters** to ask the detail of each commit:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.historyMode={searchCriteria.historyMode}&searchCriteria.includeWorkItems={searchCriteria.includeWorkItems}&searchCriteria.includeLinks={searchCriteria.includeLinks}&searchCriteria.$top={searchCriteria.$top}&searchCriteria.$skip={searchCriteria.$skip}&searchCriteria.excludeDeletes={searchCriteria.excludeDeletes}&searchCriteria.itemPath={searchCriteria.itemPath}&searchCriteria.author={searchCriteria.author}&searchCriteria.user={searchCriteria.user}&searchCriteria.toCommitId={searchCriteria.toCommitId}&searchCriteria.fromCommitId={searchCriteria.fromCommitId}&searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionOptions={searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionOptions}&searchCriteria.compareVersion.version={searchCriteria.compareVersion.version}&searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionType={searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionType}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionOptions={searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionOptions}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version={searchCriteria.itemVersion.version}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionType={searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionType}&searchCriteria.toDate={searchCriteria.toDate}&searchCriteria.fromDate={searchCriteria.fromDate}&searchCriteria.ids={searchCriteria.ids}&$skip={$skip}&$top={$top}&api-version=4.1
```

For querying work item related info should be `&searchCriteria.includeWorkItems={searchCriteria.includeWorkItems}`

More details please refer the official tutorial [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-4.1), note the API version should meet your TFS version.